# Put a value in variable using Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this csv file :

```
  Names  Credit
0    James      21
1     John      34
2    Lucas      20
3  William      11
```

And what i want to do using Pandas is : If i put any name like John , I want to add his Credit in a variable to do some math with it.

i'm  trying this :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

n = input('Enter a name: ')
x = df[df['Names'] == n]['Credit']

print(x)
```

but doesn't work for me :

```
Enter a name: John
1    30
Name: Credit, dtype: int64
```

(i'm trying to get just the number : 30)

Comment: Use: `df[df['Name'] == 'John'].loc[:, 'Credit'].squeeze()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `.squeeze()` that last dimension:

```
>>> df[df.name == 'John']['credit'].squeeze()
30
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `loc`:

```
n = input('Enter a name: ')
x = df.loc[df['Names'] == n, 'Credit']
```

Answer (score 0):

x is a pandas series, if you want only one value, you can do like this:

```
x = df[df['Names'] == n]['Credit'].tolist()[0]
```

But if you have two "John" in your data frame you will only get the credit for the first, thus make sure your Names column is always unique. If it is always unique, consider doing the following:

```
df = df.set_index('Name', drop=True)
```

This will make 'Name' the index of your data frame and then you can get the credit more easily in the following way:

```
x = df.loc[n, 'Credit']
```

Comment: Yes! I thought that too, but if he wants to query the credit just by the first name he will have to have only unique names otherwise there will be collisions